# What does nohup and & make difference when run bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook, which has a task like:

```
- name: start the apache server
  command: ./server.sh start chdir="/myapp"
```

and in the `server.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
server_wrapper.py start
```

in `server_wrapper.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import subprocess
cmd = "$APATCH_HOME/scripts/service.sh restart"
print cmd
ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
if ret !=0
  logging.critical("error happend, %d" % ret)
```

This fails randomly. when I manually ssh to the remote server which the Ansible playbook target to, I can see by run `$APACHE_HOME/scripts/service.sh restart`, the apache can successfully run, and it will output some logging to the console, things like `Apache started successfully`, seems like something with standard output.

But when run from Ansible playbook, it fails randomly, I have to change the `server.sh` in following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup server_wrapper.py start &
```

Seems that the nohup and & operator has fixed the issue.

So I want to understand why & operator fix my issue, I understand & will start a subshell and run in the background, is it something associated with standard i/o, which caused the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but I see

`cmd = "$APATCH_HOME/scripts/service.sh restart"`

Shouldn't that be `$APACHE_HOME`. (Hmm probably not because  it works when launching it locally.)

But my experience learns me that a difference between local and remote execution is mostly caused by a difference in the environment.

Try to add `set > /tmp/env_$$.out` in `server.sh` and run it both locally and with Ansible, then check the (relevant) difference in the 2 output files.